# Long String enter by user

Tags: php, string

if any user enter long string e.g aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa it destroy the layout of the page. is there any solution which dont destroy our PHP page and string also not cut?

Answer (score 5):

In your css you can use an attribute for `style` as `word-wrap:break-word;.` This will wrap or break the long word into the boundaries of your control width.

Beware this is supported only by IE, Safari and FF3.1 and above. Other browsers not sure.

Comment: @user459625: if @Sachin's answers helped you, you should vote it up and mark it as the accepted answer :D